# What is equivalent of "letter/word-spacing: initial" in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have following CSS which is working fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 11 and see a warning when I inspect an element with this style:

```
letter-spacing: initial;
word-spacing: initial;
```

How should I reset letter and word spacing to initial values in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 only supports normal, and inherit, and not initial.

So you should use 'normal'

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396